# JSTL display foreign key value associated with a primary key

Tags: jquery, sql, jstl

I am having problem trying to display a sub category menu using JSTL.

I have a css list menu type for a site I am developing. The name of the menu category is created in a database with a primary key and the submenu also created in a database and has a primary and a (foreign key = "category"). I have managed to retrieve and display this main menu but I don't know how to display the submenu when a user hovers the main menu:

Current code used:

```
//<div id='cssleftNav'>
     <ul>
         <c:forEach var = "category" items="${categories.rows}">
         <li class='has-sub'>                                            
         <a href="category?${category.id}"><span>${category.name}
         </span></a>            
         <ul>                                               
             <c:forEach var = "subcategory" items="${subcategories.rows}">
             <li>
                <a href="category?${subcategory.id}"><span>${subcategory.name}
                </span<</a>
             </li>
             </c:forEach>
         </ul>
         </li>
        </c:forEach> 
  </cssleftNav
```

Please help. I've been at this for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model is strange. You seem to have loose `${categories}` and `${subcategories}` which are not in some way referenced to each other.

You need to make sure that they reference each other. Ultimately, you'd like to end up something like as:

```html
<ul>
    <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
        <li>
            <a href="category?id=${category.id}">${category.name}</a>
            <ul>
                <c:forEach items="${category.categories}" var="subcategory">
                    <li>
                        <a href="category?id=${subcategory.id}">${subcategory.name}</a>
                    </li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

This would require a model like:

```
public class Category {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Category> categories;

    // ...
}
```

Having a `rows` property is by the way also strange. The `${categories}` should be just a `List<Category>` which you've obtained from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am new to programming  and really bad at it, after adding the following to my Category class, what do i define in the categories method

Comment: before this i also used Sessions Beans for entity class and entity class from database